# solve $y$ as a function of $t$ in equation $y′=−8\frac{t}{y}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with this problem i have for homework i got an answer but it isn't right so i need help getting the right answer with some work

Solve for y as a function of $t$ when

$y′=−8\frac{t}{y}$

when i solved the problem i got $\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{C-4t^2}$ but it isn't the right answer so i dont know what I did wrong can someone go through there solution and see if they get better answer

Comment: What is the correct answer supposed to be?

Comment: i dont know, I was wondering if someone could show me how they would solve it and what they got

Comment: You don't know the right answer, so how do you know what you got is not the right answer?

Comment: Your answer was correct, as the answers below demonstrate.

Comment: Except that he missed out the $\pm$.

Answer (score 3):

$$y'=-8\frac{t}{y}$$
$$yy'=-8t$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy^2}{dt}=-8t$$
$$y^2=\int-16tdt=-8t^2 + C$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{C-8t^2}$$

Comment: thats the right answer

Comment: @google This is equivalent to your answer. (Why?) edit: except for the $\pm$.

Answer (score 3):

$$y'=-8\frac{t}{y} \iff y'y=-8t$$
Integrate both sides :
$$\frac{y^2}{2}=-4t^2+K \iff y^2=-8t^2+2K\iff y=\pm\sqrt{2K-8t^2}=\pm\sqrt{2}\sqrt{K-4t^2} \text{(your solution minus the consideration on the sign)}$$

A cleaner way would be to write : $y(t)=\pm\sqrt{K-8t^2}, K\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is equivalent to the OP's answer, except the OP forgot the $\pm$.

Comment: last part of this solution has a slight mistake. K cannot be negative.

Answer (score 2):

General solution:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -8 \frac{t}{y} \Rightarrow \\
\int y \, dy = \int -8t \, dt \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{2}y^2 = -4t^2 + c
$$
This leads to
$$
y = \pm \sqrt{C - 8 t^2}
$$
for some constants $c$ and $C$.

Checking: 
$$
y' 
= \pm \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{C-8t^2}}(-16 t) 
= \frac{-8t}{\pm \sqrt{C-8t^2}} 
= -8 \frac{t}{y}
$$
so both roots lead to a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is variable separable, rewriting you have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dt} = -8\frac{t}{y}
\end{equation}
Multiply by $y$ and by $dt$ both sides and get:
\begin{equation}
y\,dy = -8t\, dt
\end{equation}
Now integrate both sides, LHS wrt y and RHS wrt t and get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{y^2}{2} = -4t^2 + c
\end{equation}
and finally rearranging you have:
\begin{equation}
y^2 = -8t^2+2c
\end{equation}
Then you can also take the square root if you want to